# HTML5 video in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video

Updated - Works with IE but not iphone and ipad

```
<video class="glf_video" controls="controls" autoplay>
                <source src="https://www.mydomain.com/videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                <source src="https://www.mydomain.com/videos/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
                <source src="https://www.mydomain.com/videos/video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="548" height="308" >
                    <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
                    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                    <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':['https%3A%2F%2Fwww.getlowfees.com%2Fimg%2Fvideo.jpg',{'url':'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2Fvideos%2Fvideo.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}" />
                    <img src="https://www.mydomain.com/img/video.jpg" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
                </object>
            </video>
```

Fixed in IE but now this doesn't work on the iphone. I tried exporting the video from quick time which now plays on iphone and ipad but will not play on IE.

Ugh, html 5 video is driving me crazy!!!

Comment: What do you mean when you say: `My code below works in IE when I upload it to an Apache server` Can you play the video locally?

Comment: When I tested the video on a Linux server using the above code, it played properly in IE, Chrome and Firefox. That's what leads me to believe that it's some kind of an issue with playback on IIS and locally on my Windows machine.

Comment: Watch your network traffic with Fiddler. What do you see in the failing case?

Comment: I'm getting a 304 error from Fiddler